# Keeping image within the div container

Tags: html, css

I have a simple layout and trying to keep the image within the div, but its going out of the div in full width mode, is there a way to resize image to keep within the div, I can handle is using background image but I think there must be a way to keep within the div using image tag

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/y1hnyc3d/)

```css
header {
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: #f00;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px 0;
}
header .header_left {
float: left;
width: 20%;
}
header .header_left > a > img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
header .header_right {
float: right;
width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="mcontainer">
    <div class="header_left"> <a href="javascript:;"><img src="https://cdn.img42.com/63de8c9048f1b98a226f926f5d9d56c5.jpeg" alt="Welcome"></a> </div>
    <div class="header_right">
      <ul>
        <li>Test/Test</li>
        <li>Login</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: your question is not clear to me

Comment: if you see the fiddle in full screen, I have parent div height set to 100 pixel and image within it with 100% width, image should remain within the div but its going out of it..

Comment: Why are you floating a header? Especially a full-width one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header has a fixed height of `100px` and a top and bottom padding of `10px`. So your content has a height of `80px`, so simply add `max-height:80px;` to your image:

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/y1hnyc3d/1/):**

```css
header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
header .header_left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
header .header_left > a > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height:80px;
}
header .header_right {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="mcontainer">
    <div class="header_left"> <a href="javascript:;"><img src="https://cdn.img42.com/63de8c9048f1b98a226f926f5d9d56c5.jpeg" alt="Welcome"></a> </div>
    <div class="header_right">
      <ul>
        <li>Test/Test</li>
        <li>Login</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am wondering image is going out of the div when I have width 100& in image?

Comment: Your image will be resize by `max-weight` to fit your div